# Shift Aritmetic Right operation in python

Tags: python

I'm doing a small script in python and I have to work with hex values, at some point I have to perform a shift arithmetic right operation, keeping the Most Significant Bit in its place.

I've been doing some research through python documentation (https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) and I found out that the operator **x >> y** shifts x bits y positions to the right, but that operand would destroy my Most Significant Bit. Is there some library with addition bitwise methods that I can use or do I have to create my own method? Thank you for your time.

Comment: What is it you're trying to accomplish?  Also, are you familiar with the `&` and `|` operators?  They may help you.

Comment: I'm writing a keygen for a crackme of crackmes.one, the code that I'm reversing performs an "imul %edx" (multiplies edx wiot eax, both 32 bits regisers, and stores the lowest 32 bits in %eax and the highest in %edx) and then it executes a "sar %edx, 7". This is where the question came from.

Comment: How exactly are you representing your 32-bit values? A Python `int` uses arbitrary precision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For unsigned integers, you would have to know which one is your most significant bit.  For example, if you are processing 32 bit values, you will want to protect bit 31. so the operation could be written as follows:

```
msb = 1<31              # most significant bit
n   = 123               # your 32 bit unsigned value
sn  = (n&msb) | (n>>1)  # shifted
```

Or, more simply (for signed integers)

```
sn = n // 2             # this leverages Python's infinite sized integer
                        # assuming you were able to convert your source data
                        # to a properly signed integer
```